# Displaying value from properties file in a Spring Framework View (.jsp file)?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

So I have a simple MVC set of files:
 - ObjectBuilder.java
 - Object.java
 - objectForm.jsp
 - ObjectController.java

I have a dropdown list in objectForm.jsp, that I've populated with the correct ArrayList items (examples: messageTemplate, secondTemplate).

When I choose a template in the dropdown, my controller can gather that chosen template behind-the-scenes using:

```
this.ObjectBuilder.getTemplate(object.getTemplate())
```

which takes in the chosen template and using ObjectBuilder (@Service "ObjectBuilder"), populates the template from a .properties file.

My question then is: I can display the chosen template name from the list (ex. messageTemplate) but I can't figure out how to display the .properties populated template for that chosen name. Any ideas on how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:test.properties" />` to load the properties file, than I will suggest to do something like this:

```
@Value("${yourkey}")
private String templateValue;

@ModelAttribute("template")
public String getTemplate(){
  return templateValue;
}
```

and now you can get the value in request scope. use jstl or expression language to access it on jsp.